# using join or not when using ExecutorService?

Tags: java

I am recently would like to use ExecutorService to run a bunch of threads as a pool. Once question I have is, before that I am using thread.join to wait for all threads to return, when using ExecutorService, do I still need to use join or other methods?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this "use join or other methods"?

Comment: I need to wait all threads to exist and calculate the final result,

Comment: Well, they will do both without a join.  Please be more precise.  What are you really trying to achieve.